# Special characters input string was not in a correct format

Tags: c#, .net, ms-access

I want to some text from a file and upload specific data from file to an access database
The problem is that the text contains characters such "ș, ț, ă, î, â" and in insert into comand i get "input string was not in a corect format" error.

```
 private void adauga(string s)
    {
        string[] date = s.Split(';');
        string sir;


        for (int i = 0; i < date.Length; i++)
        {
            date[i].Trim();
        }

        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
        cmd.Connection = con;

        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Meniu([id_produs], [denumire_produs], [descriere], [pret], [kcal], [felul]) VALUES('" + Convert.ToInt32(date[0]) + "','" + date[1] + "','" + date[2] + "','" + Convert.ToInt32(date[3]) + "','" + Convert.ToInt32(date[4]) + "','" + Convert.ToInt32(date[5]) + "')";

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
```

This is the code for adding a line from file.

Comment: 1. do these characters occur in one of the fields you are converting with `Convert.ToInt32`? 2. NEVER EVER construct SQL command strings from unchecked input data, use SQL Parameters instead.

Comment: No, they don't.

Comment: Can you please post a sample input line where the problem occurs?

Comment: 1;Ciorba de burta;Burtă  de vită, smântână, morcov, telină, gogosar in otet, ceapă, usturoi, otet, ouă, lapte bătut (120gr);9;400;1;

Comment: OK, this should work. But please, please consider my point 2 in the first comment!

Comment: thank you so much! i used your method, which seems more easier! i found now that the problem was with two empty lines from file and i solved this with a try catch. i'm sorry for this